# Transparency can't be layered on WPF controls?

Tags: .net, wpf, wpf-controls

I have a `Button` inside a `ContentControl` inside a `Grid`, and the button has a style giving it a certain translucent background color, the content control has another translucent background color, and finally the grid itself has its own background color. However the background of the content control seems to be ignored - it's a translucent black, whereas the button's background is a translucent blue, but the button doesn't look any darker than if I took it out of the content control. How do I make the transparency layered - that is, the content control's dark translucent background dims the background of the grid, even though there's a button inside the content control with its own translucent background?

XAML:

```
<Grid Background="{Binding ElementName=view, Path=ThemeBrush}">
    <!-- row/column definitions -->        
    <ContentControl x:Name="corner" Background="{StaticResource TranslucentDarkBrush}">
        <Button>menu</Button>
    </ContentControl>
    <!-- more controls-->
</Grid>
```

Styles used:

```
<Style TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="24"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource TranslucentDimBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource LightBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding Foreground}">
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource DimBrush}"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>

<SolidColorBrush x:Key="DarkBrush" Color="#f000"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="TranslucentDarkBrush" Color="#8000"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="DimBrush" Color="#f588"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="TranslucentDimBrush" Color="#8588"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="LightBrush" Color="#faff"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="TranslucentLightBrush" Color="#8aff"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="BrightBrush" Color="#ffff"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="TranslucentBrightBrush" Color="#8fff"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

Oh, wait, I figured it out. For some reason ContentControls are special somehow, and this doesn't work for them; I had to use a Grid.